# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I run my spring project locally I don't have any exception. But when deploying on server I get:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:450)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
at com.scoring.main.services.implementations.BlockNumberServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd6e9601.getBlockNumberPair(<generated>)
at com.scoring.main.services.implementations.ListenerServiceImpl.getAllActualTransactions(ListenerServiceImpl.java:48)
at com.scoring.main.listeners.TransactionEventListener.lambda$new$1(TransactionEventListener.java:60)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.buildEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:155)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:468)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:389)
    ... 16 more
```

I'm using Spring Data Jpa and repository class extends JpaRepository.
In logs as I undertand problem with my BlockNumberService in method getBlockNumberPair. This is how my method looks:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public BlockNumber getBlockNumberPair() {
    return blockNumberRepository.findById(1L).get();
}
```

Where is the problem and why is it works locally?

Comment: Where is your db located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by restarting server.

**UPDATE:**

That was mistake in configuration in Jenkins. I'am just pushing my project into Github and Jenkins deploys project. And as turned out after redeploying by Jenkins I've had as many started tomcat servers as I've pushed into Github and in log I've gotten that exception. But interesting how it starts a lot of processes in same port? Server just shouldn't be started in that case.